# Android compile error; Java plugin has been applied, not compatible with android

Tags: java, android, gradle, wear-os

So I've made a wearable application where I can control a robot-car with the buttons on screen with the MessageListenerService. After trying to build the project, I had some problems where it asked me to install "Android Support Repository" from the SDK, which I already had. I found another [similar problem on SO (link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620772/why-wont-android-support-libraries-work-in-my-project)  which had a sort-of solution, but now it says

> "Error: The java Plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android Plugins"

This is my build.gradle in my wearable module

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'java'


sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6   //these two lines
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6   //are the only ones that matter

android {
    compileSdkVersion 20
    buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_6
    }
signingConfigs {
    release {
        keyAlias 'C:\\Users\\Riekelt\\coolie.jks'
        keyPassword 'cut-out'
        storeFile file('path/to/release.keystore')
        storePassword 'cut-out'
    }
}

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "robowheel.robond"
    minSdkVersion 20
    targetSdkVersion 20
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release

    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:+'
compile "com.android.support:support-v4:20.0.+"
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:+'
 //   compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:6.1.11'

}
```

Anyone know what is the matter? Thanks in advancoi

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot apply both the `com.android.application` and the `java` plugin in the same module. Why are you doing that? There's nothing in the question you reference that tell you to apply the java plugin.

Remove the line with `apply plugin: 'java'`, and you're good to go

Comment: That's it. Thanks! I was following a guide to fix 1 problem, so maybe that was it? Anyway, fixed it and now I am back at my original problem...

Comment: As for your original problem, might this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590746/how-to-set-global-repositories-for-gradle-that-i-can-use-them-in-each-gradle-pro

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I'll play with it a bit later. Thanks again

Comment: Just wanted to add that this problem can also be cause by having `apply plugin: 'application'` in your code. And removing that line will also fix the problem. Well atleast it did for me

Comment: Android Studio says to `apply plugin: 'java'` for JUnit4!

Comment: Nizor, what if we want to use checkstyle, findbugs; and we need to apply java plugin. Is there any other way?

Comment: For **apply plugin: 'groovy'** also message remain same _Error:The 'java' plugin has been applied, but it is not compatible with the Android plugins._

Answer (score 67):

For those that are using kotlin and are making an Android library: make sure to use `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'` instead of `apply plugin: 'kotlin'`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing the obvious out, I ran into the same issue!

Comment: Finally, this is an issue that happens when you try to convert a Java module to an Android module.

Answer (score 2):

For those who are using corporate/company custom gradle repo, remove or fix the `init.gradle` file from your gradle home. Location on Windows is `C:\Users\User\.gradle\init.gradle`. That's where all the nasty things happen.