# Setting JavaVersion sourceCompatibility in Leiningen (Clojure) for Android (Java 1.7 vs 1.8)

Tags: java, android, clojure, leiningen

I'm trying to get Clojure compiling for Android following this tutorial : https://github.com/clojure-android/lein-droid/wiki/Tutorial

However, I'm hitting an

```
unsupported class file version 52.0
```

error.

This seems to be because I have Java 1.8, but my code needs to be compatible with 1.7 for Android projects.

[Got "unsupported class file version 52.0" after including a module to a project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902840/got-unsupported-class-file-version-52-0-after-including-a-module-to-a-project) seems to suggest I can just set the sourceCompatibility and targetCompatibility (there in the gradle build file.)

Presumably there's an equivalent in Leiningen project.clj files. But I can't find what it is.

So how can I set source and target Compatibility in Leiningen?

Answer (score 1):

OK. I managed to resolve my problem with information from here :

https://github.com/clojure-android/lein-droid/issues/161?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container

Basically it's the javac-options attribute.

```
:javac-options ["-target" "1.7" "-source" "1.7" "-Xlint:-options"]
```

But I needed to update the annotations.jar (as described on that GitHub page) too.