# Process 'command '/Applications/Android Studio 3.0.1.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Tags: java, android, android-studio, java-8, android-gradle-plugin

I came across a problem when i used android studio to import a project.More details below :
```

````
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForArmDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

And the Gradle console show the following message:

---------
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleArmDebug]
Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:copyJniLibsArmDebugMainJniLibs UP-TO-DATE
:app:armDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preArmDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkArmDebugManifest
:app:preArmReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareCjtLibraryWheelCamera019Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportCardviewV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preArmDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMultidex101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUi2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportCoreUtils2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportFragment2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportMediaCompat2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportTransition2531Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComBlankjUtilcode134Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComCjjMaterialrefeshlayoutLibrary130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDaimajiaAndroidanimationsLibrary113Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDaimajiaEasingLibrary101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDanikulaVideocache264Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComDevbracketsAndroidExomedia301Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComEdmodoCropper101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComFlycoTablayoutFlycoTabLayout_Lib212Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGetbaseFloatingactionbutton1101Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubChrisbanesPhotoView130Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubCtiaoDanmakuFlameMaster0912Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubJmolsmobileLandscapevideocamera107Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGithubSatyanSugar15Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidExoplayerExoplayerR159Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJaydenxiaoGuider100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComJcodecraeerXrecyclerview132Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMakeramenRoundedimageview230Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMalinskiySuperrecyclerview114Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComOrhanobutLogger115Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPgyersdkSdk254Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPingxxPingppAlipay218Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPingxxPingppCore218Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComPingxxPingppWxpay218Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComRengwuxianMaterialedittextLibrary214Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComScwangSmartrefreshSmartRefreshHeader103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComScwangSmartrefreshSmartRefreshLayout103Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComSerenegiantCommon119Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComZhyOkhttputils262Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDeHdodenhofCircleimageview210Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareJpWasabeefGlideTransformations202Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:preparePubDevrelEasypermissions020Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareArmDebugDependencies
:app:compileArmDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileArmDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateArmDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateArmDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeArmDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateArmDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processArmDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processArmDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateArmDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileArmDebugJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileArmDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForArmDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:collectArmDebugMultiDexComponents UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithMultidexlistForArmDebug UP-TO-DATE
:app:transformClassesWithDexForArmDebug
````

PARSE ERROR:

```
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/a/a/a.class
PARSE ERROR:
unsupported class file version 52.0
...while parsing com/a/a/b.class
2 errors; aborting
 FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
    * What went wrong:

Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForArmDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>   * Try:
>   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
>   BUILD FAILED
>   Total time: 39.744 secs

---

This android project can run well on another computer, but it can't run on current one .I hope you can help me solve this problem or give me some suggestions, thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried many solutions ,but it was failed.

Comment: `unsupported class file version 52.0` this is usually related to java version.

Comment: please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37902840/got-unsupported-class-file-version-52-0-after-including-a-module-to-a-project

Comment: I tried again,it did not work...

Comment: try using default Java compiler included in Android Studio from your project setting.

Comment: Hi J.su, did you got any solution to fix this issue, can you help me out how to fix this.

Comment: worked for you @RamKoti ? I have not found any solution yet

Answer (score 3):

Try adding this code to build.gradle > android

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This error is related to com.google.firebase and com.google.android.gms dependencies.

Upgrade them to their latest versions and the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Update your Project **build.gradle** with:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
}
```

and update all the `com.google.firebase` and `com.google.android.gms` in gradle file to newer version.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you make a new package in AndroidStudio with Camel case name. Sometimes make a crash and problem non-zero.

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced the same issue. My fix was to:

```
"build > Clean project"
"build > Generate signed APK"
```

Then the build was succesful.

I had the dexOptions set as well in mij build.gradle file.

```
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```